# Read the whole file into an array, replace one of the elements of that array, then write the whole file again. Text ends up the same

Tags: vb.net, file

I have a form3 that when the user exits it attempts to save the time they spent playing. When trying to replace the line I end up with the exact same text, therefore nothing changes in the file. Why will it not replace the text? Thanks in advance.

```
File.AppendAllLines(Application.StartupPath + "\content\main\userdata\tgametime.txt", FileLines)

'this line will not write to file if it has the same file name because FileLines is still using it, if this could be solved too awesome!
```

```
    Private Sub SaveGameTime()
        Dim fullpath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath + "\content\main\userdata\gametime.txt")
        Dim FileLines = File.ReadLines(fullpath)
        Dim alltext = File.ReadAllText(fullpath)
        Dim datalist = New List(Of String)
        Dim line
        datalist.Add(tbGameName.Text + " : " + LBtimeout.Text)
        TextDiag(FileLines.Count.ToString, "Clear")
        If FileLines.Count > 0 Then
            If alltext.Contains(tbGameName.Text) Then
                For Each line In FileLines
                    TextDiag(line, "Clear")


                    line.Replace(line, tbGameName.Text + " : " + LBtimeout.Text)
                    TextDiag("new line: " + line, "Clear")


                Next

                File.AppendAllLines(Application.StartupPath + "\content\main\userdata\tgametime.txt", FileLines)
            


            Else
                TextDiag("Line not found, adding new line", "Clear")
                File.AppendAllLines(fullpath, datalist)
            End If
        Else
            TextDiag("No lines not found, adding new line", "Clear")
            File.AppendAllLines(fullpath, datalist)
        End If

        datalist.Clear()
        fullpath = Nothing
        FileLines = Nothing
        datalist = Nothing
```

[TextDiag Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8ckm.png)

Comment: Well, would expect exactly what you're describing, you are using File.AppendAllLines().  It's in the name.  It Appends to the file(as in adds to the bottom of the file).  Options are to either clear the file and re-write it in entirety or actually just append new lines

Comment: Also _Dim fullpath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath + "\content\main\userdata\gametime.txt")_  while I applaud the use of Path.Combine() it's kind of redundant when you feed it a full path.  Better to use it properly and combine each folder of the path.  Something like Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "content", "main", "userdata", Path.ChangeExtension("gametime", "txt"))

Comment: And final comment. **&** for concatenating strings, **+** is an arithmetic operator

Comment: @Hursey So use StreamWriter instead? and thanks for tips.

Comment: Please describe in detail what you're actually trying to achieve, perhaps with an example. It sounds like what you need to do is read the whole file, possibly into an array, replace one of the elements of that array, then write the whole file again. It's hard to know for sure though, because your description is too vague. We should have to work out what you're trying to do from code that doesn't actually do it.

Comment: @John You hit it on the head! That's exactly it.

Comment: Then do that. Why are you calling `AppendAllInes` when you don't want to append. Call `ReadAllLines`, loop over the lines and process them as required, then call `WriteAllLines`.

Comment: @John I want to solve the file in use thing first but good point. I was however changed it while experimenting.

Comment: If the file isn't to large, the easiest option is to read in one go, process in a loop and then write in one go. If the file is or might be large, you can call File.ReadLines and process as you read, wiring out to a temp file as you go. When you're done, move the temp file to overwrite the original.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, replaces text at a specified string value in a file formatted like this: "Text > 0 : 0 : 0" . It gets a new time value extracted from a label formatted like this: "0 : 0 : 0", removes everything but the numbers and colons to this: "0:0:0", formats them to a TimeSpan and adds them to the outputlines which also contain any other original text.

- Thank you

```
  Dim fullpath = "yourpath"
        Dim FileLines = File.ReadLines(fullpath)
        Dim outputlines As New List(Of String)
        Dim alltext = File.ReadAllText(fullpath)
        Dim datalist = New List(Of String)
        Dim line
        Dim lbtime = TimeSpan.Parse(LBtimeout.Text.Replace(" ", ""))
       
        datalist.Add("youstring" + " : " + "yourstring")
     
        If FileLines.Count > 0 Then
            If alltext.Contains("yourstring") Then
                For Each line In FileLines
                    If line.contains("yourstring") Then
                      
                        Dim liness = line.substring(line.indexof(">") + 1)
                        Dim linerep = liness.replace(" ", "")
                    
                        Dim linetime = TimeSpan.Parse(linerep)
                      
                        Dim timesum As TimeSpan = lbtime + linetime
                        line.replace(line, "")
                        line = "yourstring" + " > " + timesum.ToString
                       
                        outputlines.Add(line)
                    Else
                        outputlines.Add(line)
                    End If
                Next

               
                File.WriteAllLines("yourpath", outputlines)



            Else
               
                File.AppendAllLines(fullpath, datalist)
            End If
        Else
            'No lines not found, adding new line
            File.AppendAllLines(fullpath, datalist)
        End If

        datalist.Clear()
        fullpath = Nothing
        FileLines = Nothing
        datalist = Nothing
```